# Resize A Browser Window And Take A Screenshot

Tags: javascript

Each week I have to take a screenshot of a certain web page to show progress.

This involves opening the page in firefox, logging in, resizing the page to certain dimensions (for consistency and ease of comparing screenshots) then using the full page screenshot feature of firefox to capture the full page as it doesn't fit on the monitor.

Ideally, it would be good to be able to automate the whole process.

However, at the moment I just want to work out how to resize the current window and how to take a full page screenshot.

**NB:** I tagged javascript as I was thinking of a userjs script, however, I am open to alternatives as long as I can run it on linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) to open the browser, resize it, and take a screenshot! Here is the code:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      // Change this with the size you need
      defaultViewport: {width: 1920, height: 1080}
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://stackoverflow.com/', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
  // Wait until page has loaded completely
  // Make a screenshot
  await page.screenshot({path: 'screenshot.png'});
  await browser.close();
})();
```

I hope it helps!

Here is the Puppeteer repository for more info: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer